# リンク切れ: 質問投稿画面の右サイドの「質問の聞き方を参考」というリンク

Tags: バグ, 完了, ハイパーリンク

質問投稿画面の右サイドに「質問の聞き方を参考」というリンクがあるが、そこをクリックすると「ページが見つかりません」になってしまう。
リンクのURLが間違っている事が原因と思われる。
(誤) https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta
(正) https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本件、リンクが修正されている事を確認しました。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask